# File content changes when copied to another file

Tags: file, visual-foxpro

I am parsing database file based on VisualFoxPro database(.dbf file),all data are assembled into just one file with tags in between telling where the files are splited.I have written codes to split files in to simple files,which is just the form VisualFoxPro creates it.But VFP can not parse the file.

I find out that when I open a fine file I just created from VisualFoxPro,everything goes well.But the file can't be read after a copied all characters to another file.I tried this in notepad++,MS notepad,MS word, the results are the same(the hex file are just the same before and after,but still cna be parsed).
Also I see lots of "NUL"s in notepad++, they just disappeared when I copy and paste the file into new file.What could go wrong?

Comment: What for you need to split these files?

Comment: My professional working software created such in-one file(originally these files are connected together with tags tell where to split),each part stores just one table of my professional work - .And I need to operate the data in each part(cause the interface of the software is too inconvenient to use).That's why I have to split it so that i could parse the dbf data using database.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever open and edit a DBF file in notepad++, notepad, word ...??? They are all text editors BUT the DBF files are binary (a DBF file can contain any ASCII characters including Character 0x00 - mostly in its header).

You can still combine and split DBF files, but to do that you should use coding and do that with binary read & write.

What language are you using? If you tell us we could possibly help with code in the language you use.

This is the shortest sample that I came up with using Python:

```
import glob, zipfile

sourceFiles = r"c:\MyData\*.*"
targetFile  = r"c:\MyDataBackup\MySingleFile.zip"

with zipfile.ZipFile(targetFile, 'w') as zf:
    for f in glob.glob(sourceFiles):
        zf.write(f)
```

Basically the difference is this one is compressed. You can instead do it like you wanted:

```
import os, glob

sourceFiles = r"c:\MyData\*.*"
targetFile  = r"c:\MyDataBackup\MySingleFile.dat"

targetFolder= r"c:\MyDataBackup"

## Writer  - create single file
with open(targetFile, 'wb') as fw:
    for f in glob.glob(sourceFiles):
        fileName = os.path.basename(f)
        fileSize = os.path.getsize(f)
        fh = "{0:100}{1:10d}".format(fileName, fileSize)

        # write header
        fw.write( bytearray(fh,'utf-8') ) 

        with open(f, 'rb') as fr:
            fw.write(fr.read())


# reader - restore back from single file
with open(targetFile, 'rb') as fr:
    fileInfo = fr.read(110)
    while fileInfo:
        fileName = fileInfo[:100].decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        fileSize = int(fileInfo[-10:].decode('utf-8').lstrip())

        outFile = targetFolder +'\\'+ fileName
        with open(outFile , 'wb') as fw:
            fw.write( fr.read( fileSize ) ) 

        fileInfo = fr.read(110)
```

Comment: umm..python,that's I can only use.And I actually did used binary read&write.But FoxPro just doesn't recognize the files I've splited..                          by the way I've tried to read all the characters and translated them into hex codes.I compared the content before-and-after I simply copy-and-paste the contents in text editor.They are just the same..But why FoxPro doesn't recognize the pasted text?!

Comment: Still couldn't understand what and why you try to do, but maybe simple `SELECT ... INTO ...` by row numbers can help you to split a DBF file.

Comment: @Oleg    but that file can not yet be read by FoxPro,it says it is not a table, so I can not use any database link commands.          ---the whole original file structure is like: file header(software version)...TableName1...TableContent...TableName2...TableContent2...etc. And only TableContent parts are the data that can be read by FoxPro.That's why I have to split the original file.

Comment: I didn't yet have time to create a reader / writer in Pyhton. You are saying Header .... TableName1 ... TableContent .... TableName2 .... That structure doesn't seem to be reasonable. Don't you also keep the TableContentSize? If not, how do you know where a TableContent starts and ends?

Comment: I added the python codes. They are tested to work. (But I don't understand the need to do that)

Comment: @BSider, you can email to me cetin dot basoz at deu dot edu dot tr. Please include the code that you used to read and write that.